# Listen for Server response using Scarlet

Tags: java, android, kotlin

so I have recently used scarlet WebSocket to successfully send data to my server online but the issue is that I am supposed to get a response from the server but am not getting anything.
below is my code:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    @SuppressLint("CheckResult")
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val socketInit = ServerClass(application)
        socketInit.socket.observeWebSocketEvent()
            .filter { it is WebSocket.Event.OnConnectionOpened<*> }
            .subscribe({
                val data =  "{ \"lat\": 40.5555555555, \"lng\": 37.55564555554545, \"userId\": 2}"
                val send = LocationAction(data =data)

                socketInit.socket.subscribe(send)
                Log.d("TAG_SUB",send.toString())


        },{
            Log.e("TAG", "Error while observing socket ${it.cause}")
        })


        socketInit.socket.observeTicker().subscribe({
            idText.text  =it
            Log.d("TAG", "Observed: $it")
        },
            {
                Log.e("TAG", "Error while observing ticker ${it.cause}")
            })


    }

}
```

here is my interface

```
interface SocketService {
    @Receive
    fun observeWebSocketEvent(): Flowable<WebSocket.Event>
    @Send
    fun subscribe(action: LocationAction)

    @Receive
    fun observeTicker(): Flowable<String>
}
```

this class bellow hold my scarlet implementation and my socket url

```
class ServerClass(application: Application): MainApplication() {

    private val lifecycle = AndroidLifecycle.ofApplicationForeground(application = application)
    private val backoffStrategy = ExponentialWithJitterBackoffStrategy(5000, 5000)

    private val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .connectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .readTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .writeTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .build()

    val socket = Scarlet.Builder()
        .webSocketFactory(okHttpClient.newWebSocketFactory("https://staging.kross.app/api/v1/notification/update"))
        .addMessageAdapterFactory(MoshiMessageAdapter.Factory())
        .addStreamAdapterFactory(RxJava2StreamAdapterFactory())
        .backoffStrategy(backoffStrategy)
        .lifecycle(lifecycle)
        .build()
        .create<SocketService>()


}
```

The observeTicker function should be where I listen for my response from the server but nothing is happening. Please I need help

Comment: Were you able to find a solution? I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

I was experiencing the same problem, until I found a way to catch the messages coming from the socket.

I'm catching the messages this way:

```
        socketInit.socket.observeWebSocketEvent()               
            .subscribe {
                when (it) {
                    is WebSocketEvent.OnConnectionOpened -> {
                        //I do the Subscription Here the 1st message to the webserver 
                    }

                    is WebSocketEvent.OnConnectionClosing -> {
                        //Connection Closing
                    }

                    is WebSocketEvent.OnConnectionFailed -> {
                        //If connection fails
                    }

                    is WebSocketEvent.OnMessageReceived -> {                          
                        //I'm doing it here!! If you parse the it.message.toString()
                        //You can transform the response into a JSON Object like this
                        val x  : Response = Gson().fromJson(it.message.toString(), Response::class.java) 
                    }
```

I hope this will help you

Comment: What you did is right but its not the proper way. GsonConverterFactory supposed to do this in its own by trigger either the observerWebSocketEvents or the @Send observeResponse. Can you provide as what you finally did??

Comment: Ever figured that one out?